# Dynamically display results from an unkown SOQL query

Tags: apex, visualforce, soql, dynamic-soql

I want to do some investigation of how the data looks in my Salesforce org, so I'd like to have a simple Visualforce page that takes an query string as an input and then display the results in a pageBlockTable (or whatever will work)

```
<apex:page controller="Cntrlr_soqlQuery">
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock title="Enter your SOQL Query">
            <apex:pageMessages ></apex:pageMessages>
            <apex:inputTextarea id="query" value="{!query}" styleClass="query" />
            <br/>
            <apex:commandButton action="{!runQuery}" value="Submit Query"/>
            <br/>
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!result}" var="r" rendered="{!showResult}">
                <apex:repeat value="{!fields}" var="f" rendered="{!showResult}">
                    <apex:column headerValue="{!f}">{!r[f]}</apex:column>
                </apex:repeat>
            </apex:pageBlockTable>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

with controller

```
public class Cntrlr_soqlQuery { 

    public string query {get;set;}
    public list<string> fields {get;set;}
    public list<sObject> result {get;set;}
    public boolean showResult {get;set;}

    public Cntrlr_soqlQuery(){
        showResult=false;
    }//END init

    public pageReference runQuery(){
        fields=query.toLowerCase().substringBefore('from').substringAfter('select').split(',');
        for(string f:fields){
            if(f.contains(')')  //for AggregateResults
                f=f.substringAfter(')');
            f=f.deleteWhiteSpace();
        }
        try{
            result=database.query(query);
        } catch(exception e){
            ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.severity.ERROR,'Malformed SOQL query.  Error: '+e));
        }
        showResult=true;
        return null;
    }//END runQuery

}//END class
```

But I get errors like `"Exception: Invalid field *** for ####"`

I'm guessing one reason this isn't working is because the VF page doesn't know what type the data is (string, integer, decimal, etc.), but I can't figure it out.

---

One idea I have is to create a map> to send each record to an integer and then each field to a string (of that field name and the data-type cast as a string)...but that isn't as elegant as I'm hoping for.

Any ideas?

Comment: Where in `Cntrlr_soqlQuery` is the invalid field exception occurring? Is it the `database.query(query);` call? Also, have you tried the Developer Console for running one off SOQL queries and checking the results?

Comment: Take a look at [Dynamic Visualforce Components](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_dynamic_vf_components_sample.htm#pages_dynamic_vf_components_sample)

Comment: The controller isn't throwing an exception.  The visualforce page is throwing an error trying to display the results

Comment: @DanielHoechst I came across Dynamic Components before, and I'll take a closer look to see what it can do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I appreciate that this does not meet the **title** of the question, but perhaps does satisfy the underlying requirement: "I want to do some investigation of how the data looks in my Salesforce org"

Have you seen the Salesforce Developer Console?
Your Name > Developer Console

You can run queries and get a tabulated output:

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I'm trying to do.  Heh, I was working too hard!

Comment: In a way its a shame - Visualforce Dynamic Bindings and Dynamic Visualforce Components are a nice topic :-)

Comment: Sometimes we get so deep in the technical details of what is trying to be done, we forget to ask why is it trying to be done?

Comment: Ohh Stephen, you and your Dynamic Visualforce Components :) jesting aside, I really would like to read yours ideas about Dynamic Visualforce Components. Do you have a blog?

Comment: Ah yes Daniel (Blackhall) our previous discussion of DVCs! I do have a blog, but haven't touched the topic of DVCs yet. If we wanted to build a solution to the original question then this would be a pretty good use case for DVCs, so I do like the idea of using it as a example for a blog post...

Comment: Yes, so very easy to do Daniel (Hoechst)

Answer (score 2):

It's not a fix for your code, but there is a project on Google Code which already does this:

[soql-query-tool](https://code.google.com/p/soql-query-tool/)

It performs all operations using the [ajax toolkit](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/ajax/). Meaning there is no Apex Controller, it is all done using javascript. This is a big change from how you were looking to solve the problem, but someone else has done all the hard work :)

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative to rolling your own: Try out the [Developer Workbench](https://workbench.developerforce.com/login.php):